# Can protobuf-csharp-port work on webplayer?

Tags: unity-game-engine

We can't call any dll on webplayer, but protobuf-csharp-port uses dll extensions, so seems that it doesn't work on webplayer. Anyone who can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can use dlls in the webplayer as long as they contain pure managed c# code. You can't use native dlls written in c++ for example.

These dlls shouldn't use any kind of reflection as it is an excluded sub-assembly in unity webplayer.

I don't know if protobuf-csharp-port matches these constraints but if you are looking for a nice protocol buffer implementation, you can have a look at [protobuf-net](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) which is a very nice one, written in pure c#. There is a specific unity-compatible build in the distribution. You can even compile your protobuf serializers in a custom dll so no reflection is used to be webplayer compliant.